# Mean and variance and special distribution of events

Tags: mean, dispersion, compound-distributions

> A hospital Accident and Emergency (A&E) department receives an average of 6    ambulances an hour. It can process patients in 30 minutes, but if it receives more  than five patients in 30 minutes, a state of emergency will be declared, and the A&E    department will shut. Each ambulance will arrive with either 1, 2, or 3 patients,   with relative probabilities of 0.7, 0.2 and 0.1 respectively.
>
> i.    Calculate the dispersion index of the arrival of the patients and comment on        the nature of their arrival.
>
> ii.    Calculate the mean and variance of the number of patients arriving over one hour.

This is my attempt so far but I’m not sure now if I’ve done it right.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer for (i) seem OK. Here is some help getting started with (ii). [You don't ask about the probability of declaring an emergency because of having too many arrivals in half an hour.]

The number of ambulance arrivals in an hour is
$A \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 6).$
Then you have a problem involving a random number of
random variables to find the distribution of the number $X$
of *patients* per hour. The mean and variance of the number of patients in an ambulance should help with that. Notice that $Var(X)$ has [two components](http://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/Conditionals/RandomSums/randsum.shtml).

Simulation of number $X$ of patients arriving per hour, with $E(X) = 8.4:$

```
set.seed(2020)
x = replicate(10^6, 
 sum( sample(1:3, rpois(1,6), rep=T, prob=c(.7,.2,.1))) )
mean(x); var(x)
[1] 8.400893  # aprx E(X) = 8.4
[1] 14.39057  # aprx Var(X)

cutp = -1:max(x) + .5
hdr="Simulated Hourly Patient Arrivals"
hist(x, prob=T, br=cutp, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant I got the mean in the end to be 8.4 I did it doing 1.4*6 but I got my variance to be 2.64 by doing 0.44*6. Is that not the way to do it?

Comment: Try variance formula again. Be careful not to mix up A's, N's and X's when using formula in link.  I got exact variance computation to be 14.4 which matches my simulated value within sim error.// Something about the variance formula seems to beg for getting wrong answ the first time.

Comment: fabulous thank you I’ve got it!

Comment: The link seems to be dead, but the Wayback Machine [has a snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808171457/http://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/Conditionals/RandomSums/randsum.shtml).